# A specific mollified functions in the Sobolev space H^1(R)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $u>0$ be in $H^{1}(\mathbb{R})=W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$, we know that the set of $C^{\infty}$ functions with compact support are dense in the Sobolev space $H^{1}(\mathbb{R})$. Hence, we have a sequence $u_n$ (convolution +cut-off) which converges toward to $u$ using the $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ norm.

Can I impose the condition $u_n(x)\leq u(x)$ a.e?

Comment: If you insist on constructing it from convolution against a mollifier: no. But if you just want a sequence of smooth approximations: yes.

Comment: Rough sketch: since $u > 0$, you can find a sequence $R_n \nearrow \infty$ and $\epsilon_n \searrow 0$ such that the functions $$ v_n = \chi_{[-R_n, R_n]}\cdot (u - \epsilon_n) $$ is non-negative and converges to $u$ in $H^1$. For each $v_n$ you can mollify. Then you can diagonalize and use the fact that $u\in H^1 \implies u$ is uniformly continuous to ensure the smoothed versions of $v_n$ remains below $u$.

Comment: Thank for your answer, it is not necessary to have a convolution against mollifier. I just want a sequence of $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ with compact support and the condition $|u_n(x)|\leq u(x)$ a.e.

Comment: Can you please explain more how to transform the functions $v_n$ into a functions in $C^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R})$ which converge toward to $u$ using the $H^{1}$ norm and maintain the condition $|v_n(x)|\leq u(x)$ a.e.

Comment: Do the usual thing by convolving with a smooth bump function; call the smoothed versions $v_{n,\epsilon}$. Since $v_{n,\epsilon} \to v_n$ in $H^1$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, and $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ embeds in $L^\infty$, the $\epsilon_n$ room you left in step one is big enough. // You can be even more precise by using uniform continuity to show that as long as your smooth bump function has sufficiently small support this will work.

Comment: Ok for convolution. Now, as well as I understand the goal is to show that $\forall \varepsilon'>0$, for $n$ large enough and $\varepsilon$ small enough we have 

$$\Vert v_{n,\varepsilon}-u\Vert_{H^1(\mathbb{R})}\leq \Vert v_{n,\varepsilon}-v_{n}\Vert_{H^1(\mathbb{R})}+\Vert v_{n}-u\Vert_{H^1(\mathbb{R})}\leq \frac{\varepsilon'}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon'}{2}\leq\varepsilon'.$$

Comment: Then I have two questions. First, why $\Vert \nabla v_{n}-\nabla u\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}\longrightarrow 0$ as $n\longrightarrow \infty$? And how can prove using the uniform continuity the fact that $|v_{n,\varepsilon}(x)|\leq u(x)$? Thanks

Comment: Could you please send any references you might have

Comment: These questions are extremely elementary and you should probably ask on Math.SE instead. But a sketch of (1): the cut-off function $\chi_{[-R,R]}$ is (implicitly in the argument above) smooth. In fact, you **should** know how to do this since that's half of the method you quoted in the question body itself. For (2) a hint: convolution by a non-negative bump function of integral one can only reduce the oscillation.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in some of the comments.

Let $0 \le \eta_n (x) \le 1$ be a sequence of smooth functions $\eta_n = 1$ in $[-n, n]$ and $\eta_n \in [-(n+1), n+1]$. Simply take $u_n = \eta_n \cdot u$. Basically by taking a smooth transition function in $(0,1)$.

Then
$$ \| u_n' - u' \|_{L^2} \le \| \eta_n ' u \|_{L^2} + \| \eta_n u' - u' \|_{L^2} \le C \left( \int_{n <|x| < n + 1} |u|^2 \right)^{\frac 1 n} + \left( \int_{|x|>n} |u'|^2 \right)^{\frac 1 n} \to 0 $$
as $n \to \infty$. The $\| u_n - u \|_{L^2} \to 0$ I leave for you.